# Django 1.8.13 queryset works once, then fails

Tags: python, django

I have very strange error in Django.

My queryset looks like:

```
return (
    Post.objects
    .select_related(
        'channel',
    )
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('poll', queryset=(
            Poll.objects.prefetch_related('choice_set')
        )),
        Prefetch('author__profile', queryset=(
            UserProfile.objects
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('major', queryset=Major.objects.only('name')),
                Prefetch('university', queryset=University.objects.only(
                    'longname',
                )),
            )
            .only(
                ...
            )
        )),
    )
    .only(
        ...
    )
)
```

And now, when I run Django dev server and I go straigt to this view, it works for the first time, objects are correct. Next time, it fails with:

```
AttributeError: Cannot find ‘author’ on UserProfile_Deferred_campaign_id_city_id_country8db75c0f1ddc0935cac6f1c9c2d0cda2 object, ‘author__profile__major’ is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

The same thing is with unit tests, if test for this view is ran first, it works, when I run all tests, it fails (and its not first then).

What am I doing wrong? Between first and second try there are no new objects created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue, this is related to a bug which got fixed in 1.9 - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24873.